How to integrate MobilePay with flutter app using Stripe?
I have been working on market place that uses flutter at mobile side and Laravel as backend .
I already have read stripe documentation about Mobile Pay , However it does not provide more details about handling payment with mobile pay.
Here is my Laravel example code for creating paymentIntent
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $paymentIntent = $this->stripe->paymentIntents->create([
            'amount' => $request->amount,
            'currency' => $request->currency,
            'customer' => $request->customer_id,
            'payment_method_types' => [
                'card',
                'mobilepay',
                'klarna'
            ],
           
        ]);
        Log::info($paymentIntent);
        return response()->json([
            'client_secret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
            'paymentIntent' => $paymentIntent,
        ]);
    }

// example json object

[2024-07-19 13:28:45] staging.INFO: Stripe\PaymentIntent JSON: {
    "id": "pi_3PeE3NIdrrbatSEw1yw67eje",
    "object": "payment_intent",
    "amount": 10000,
    "amount_capturable": 0,
    "amount_details": {
        "tip": []
    },
    "amount_received": 0,
    "application": null,
    "application_fee_amount": null,
    "automatic_payment_methods": null,
    "canceled_at": null,
    "cancellation_reason": null,
    "capture_method": "automatic",
    "charges": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "\/v1\/charges?payment_intent=pi_3PeE3NIdrrbatSEw1yw67eje"
    },
    "client_secret": "pi_3PeE3NIdrrbatSEw1yw67eje_secret_t8saAgTE9eTzMi2qT8qqt1HYK",
    "confirmation_method": "automatic",
    "created": 1721384925,
    "currency": "eur",
    "customer": "cus_QUqW1uGNzdoybm",
    "description": null,
    "invoice": null,
    "last_payment_error": null,
    "latest_charge": null,
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": [],
    "next_action": null,
    "on_behalf_of": null,
    "payment_method": null,
    "payment_method_configuration_details": null,
    "payment_method_options": {
        "card": {
            "installments": null,
            "mandate_options": null,
            "network": null,
            "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
        },
        "klarna": {
            "preferred_locale": null
        },
        "mobilepay": []
    },
    "payment_method_types": [
        "card",
        "mobilepay",
        "klarna"
    ],
    "processing": null,
    "receipt_email": "user@example.com",
    "review": null,
    "setup_future_usage": null,
    "shipping": null,
    "source": null,
    "statement_descriptor": null,
    "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
    "status": "requires_payment_method",
    "transfer_data": null,
    "transfer_group": null
}  


Now At flutter Side , it is very straight forward to handle payment with card , however for Mobile Pay how i can trigger flow to launch app and charge money from User and then send a callback to my backend server to update status .
I have seen MobilePay Documentation Mobile Pay Developer Documentation and according to them i have to seperately registered with them and implement mobile pay using Kotlin (Android ) and then Swift( for IOS). I am doing something wrong because for me it feels like too much work and either i am missing something in stripe setting to capture payment from MobilePay.
I am also attaching a screenshot from my stripe Payment methods that mobile pay is enabled.

Her is my mobile app screenshot to show what my payment page looks like


Thanks in advance

What code have you written in the app to process the payment? Stripe has docs on this(but note the Flutter library is a third-party wrapper around their React Native library) : either you just use your normal existing PaymentSheet integration and MobilePay is one of the options in it : https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native , or you can directly confirm a PaymentIntent as described at https://docs.stripe.com/payments/mobilepay/accept-a-payment?web-or-mobile=mobile&payments-ui-type=react-native#confirm-payment-intent

thanks for your comment , however , i found that Stripe does not have official support for mobile pay on mobile . https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/discussions/1625?sort=new.
I think i will have to use native code and then built a package in flutter to use native api for mobile pay .

To clarify, Stripe does have official support in their mobile/RN SDKs. flutter_stripe is a third-party/community project.

I also highly suspect that if you use PaymentSheet in your integration, it would just work regardless of versions of the flutter SDK, since there's no MobilePay-specific code needed, it's just part of the PaymentSheet.

I decided to create a flutter package that uses these native implementation and call it from flutter . will share link here for others
